# z-index hover over not working

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a hover over event that won't effect the rest of my layout.  It seems that z-index is the way to do that but I can't get it to work.  I'm trying to stick with css but jQuery is doable.

full app: http://jsfiddle.net/9cRdq/

html

```
<div class="big-square" id="br">
    <div class="little-square" id="br-tl"></div>
    <div class="little-square" id="br-tr"></div>
    <div class="little-square" id="br-bl"></div>
    <div class="little-square" id="br-br"> </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.big-square
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 2em;
    float: left;
    width: 30%; 
    min-width: 4em;
    min-height: 4em;
    margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
    background: #000;
}
.little-square
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    width: 48%; 
    height: 48%;
    background: #cd2626;
}
.little-square:hover
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(resizeBigSquare);
window.onresize = resizeBigSquare;
function resizeBigSquare() {
    $('.big-square').css(
        {
            'height': ($('.big-square').width() * .85) + 'px',
            'line-height': ($('.big-square').width() * .85) + 'px'
        });
    $('.little-square, .rectangle-top, .rectangle-bottom').css(
        {
            'line-height': $('.little-square').height()+ 'px'
        });
}
```

Comment: I think you can not use float and position together. basically float renders the document after other elements are placed. same as position attribute. so I think if you want to use z-index hover get rid of floats.

Comment: I removed the floats and it's still not working.

Comment: @user1134179 I think the z-index does change, but the fact that nothing else happens visually, you wouldn't notice a change.

Comment: The 'little square' div isn't inside the 'big-square' div

Comment: Have any recommendations on how to scale up/down the div without effecting the rest of the layout?

Comment: yes correct `vinny` because the elements are contained within the big square in order to see the effect they should not be contained in each other. thats the idea.. `<big-square/><little-square/>`

Comment: What effect are you looking for, visually, when a little-square is hovered?

Comment: To either increase or decrease the height and width of the currently hovered over area without effecting the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `z-index` change on hover is working just fine. In fact, [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cRdq/2/) that shows it working via the use of `box-shadow`. Your **div.little-square** is actually above it's peers when hovered over it, otherwise the `box-shadow` would clip behind the others.

Note that `z-index` only affects stacking order on the z-axis, nothing else (size, color, etc.)

If you're looking to change the size of **div.little-square** on hover (without breaking the grid), consider creating a child element inside each square instead. Then, apply `position:absolute` to the new child element, transfer some properties of the little-square over to it, and style it's hover state accordingly. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cRdq/3/) has an example of what I'm talking about.